# Bring third party app to the front

Tags: android

i'm trying to bring a third Party app to the front if it is on stack..

This is the best Approach i was able to find, but it is not working well regarding to the comments under the first answere..

[How to bring most recently used third party Activity to front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080177/how-to-bring-most-recently-used-third-party-activity-to-front)

The common Approach is an Intent:

```
Intent myIntent = getPackageManager.getLaunchIntent("packageName of third Party app");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

this works in some cases.. but not in all.

So i tried to set the right flag regarding to the Android docs:

```
myIntent.setFLags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK:

**When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in. See FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK for a flag to disable this behavior.**

Issue stays the same. There must be a way, because OS is doing this everytime you click on the Icon of the app which is already on the stack.. it brings the current Task to the front for every app..

So, is there a way to bring the current Task to the front of every third Party application i want to? Or is just the OS allowed to do so?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following..

Intent intent = **getPackageManager**().**getLauncherIntentForPackage**("thirdPartyPackageName");
                  startActivity(intent);

I have tested this with 4 different third party applications.. It works fine .

Comment: Please read the questionc carefully... this is the first and simplest Approach. It works on some app. But not for all. Try Messages for example. Open a new Message in Messages minimize the activity and start Messages from your activity. You won't be at the "New Message" activity anymore..